# PHP Get JSON from a URL that has a query string

Tags: php, json, query-string

I have a URL that is like this: https://web.site.com/file.json?key=xxxxxxxxx

It is from an external site that provides Jackpot data.

Entering that URL in a browser returns proper JSON, but when I try to get that URL in PHP, it does not return anything.

I've created a test JSON file on the same server, and a test JSON file on another server with the same data and it works correctly when calling it like this:

```
<?php
   $url = 'https://web.site.com/file.json';
   $data = file_get_contents($url);
   $json = json_decode($data);
   echo $json->type;
?>
```

But as soon as the query string is in the URL, I run into a problem.

Comment: when you pass a query string what is the response content being returned? have you tried echoing the content of the `$data` before you decode it as JSON?You are also likely getting some warnings

Comment: This is what's generated through the URL in a browser: {"type":"Jackpot","available_tickets":29000,"ordered_total":"9495.0000"}

Just echoing $json through php returns nothing.  Echoing $json->type gives this error: Trying to get property 'type' of non-object in ... on line 5 which is the $json->type line.

Comment: As above you mention you are passing `key=xxx` as a query parameter in request that not found in your php script.

Comment: Second thing after using `json_decode` you can't use `->` this OF sign. You have to use `$json['type']`, not `$json->type`